# Pandas Replace missing date(string) with count of 0 for each location

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with Location, Date and Count.  The Date is stored as a string and is just for the month of November 2018.  There are 68 locations.  Some dates and locations have more than one count and I want to keep those rows the way they are.  What I am looking for help on is, if a location does not have a date within 2018-11-01 and 2018-11-30 I would like to add a row with the location, missing date(string), and a count of "0" .  This is my dataframe:

```
    Location        Date        Count
0   location_one    2018-11-06  102
1   location_one    2018-11-06  16
2   location_one    2018-11-06  650
3   location_one    2018-11-07  4
4   location_one    2018-11-06  12
5   location_one    2018-11-06  191
6   location_one    2018-11-06  58
7   location_one    2018-11-07  149
```

Desired output:

```
    Location        Date        Count
0   location_one    2018-11-01  0
1   location_one    2018-11-02  0
2   location_one    2018-11-03  0
3   location_one    2018-11-04  0
4   location_one    2018-11-05  0
5   location_one    2018-11-06  102
6   location_one    2018-11-06  16
7   location_one    2018-11-06  650
8   location_one    2018-11-07  4
9   location_one    2018-11-06  12
10  location_one    2018-11-06  191
11  location_one    2018-11-06  58
12  location_one    2018-11-07  149
```

Comment: build a dataframe ,with Date ,range then merge it back

Comment: Where are the dates from 2018-11-08 to 2018-11-30?

Comment: Can I add 10023 rows on here?

Comment: Is better if you don't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expands previous answers to work with multiple locations per OP.

```
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['location_one', '2018-11-06', '102'],
    ['location_one', '2018-11-06', '16'],
    ['location_one', '2018-11-06', '650'],
    ['location_one', '2018-11-07', '4'],
    ['location_one', '2018-11-06', '12'],
    ['location_one', '2018-11-06', '191'],
    ['location_one', '2018-11-06', '58'],
    ['location_one', '2018-11-07', '149'],
    ['location_two', '2018-11-06', '110'] # Added
], columns=['location', 'date', 'count'])

# (1) Create dataframe for all dates in Nov 2018
month = '2018-11'
date_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-11-01',end='2018-11-30',freq='d')}
)
date_df.date = date_df.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# (2) Create dataframe with every location/date combination
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    input_df.location.unique(), 
    date_df.date
], names = ['location', 'date'])
master_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index).reset_index()

# (3) Populate count column and fill missing entries with zero
results = pd.merge(master_df, input_df, on=['location', 'date'], how='left').fillna(0)
print(results)
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it's better at handling some additional info you got from the question. Specifically, we don't know what the dtype is for the date field. This solution works even if it is a string. My answer assumes a datetime in the `Date` field.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the comment by W-B:

Assuming you start with `df` as:

```
  Location        Date        Count
 0   location_one    2018-11-06  102
 1   location_one    2018-11-06  16
 2   location_one    2018-11-06  650
 3   location_one    2018-11-07  4
 4   location_one    2018-11-06  12
 5   location_one    2018-11-06  191
 6   location_one    2018-11-06  58
 7   location_one    2018-11-07  149
```

You could then do:

```
 t_df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-11-01',end='2018-11-30',freq='d')})
 result = t_df.merge(df,how='left').fillna(0) #Assumes no nas in other fields
```